# What happens in elasticsearch if provided in match object does not exist?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, my query has something like this:

```
"must": {
    "match": {
        "parentObj.obj.property": "Foo"
    }
}
```

What will be the output, if `obj` does not exist at all, so we can not take `property` of nothing? Those `hits` without `obj` will be declined or it will be ignored and those `hits` will stay?

Answer (score 0):

You will not get any hits for objects that are missing the `obj` property.